# How can I get the new CGPath that represents a scaled SKShapeNode?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

An SKShapeNode that was scaled using SKActions, like this:

```
var shapeNode: SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(points: UnsafeMutablePointer(points), count: points.count)  
shapeNode.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(16, duration: 2))
```

I would like to then update the node's SKPhysicBody to match its new size:

```
shapeNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: shapeNode.path)
```

However, it looks like `shapeNode.path` returns the path at its original size, not the path at its new size.

Is there a way to get the path of the new size?

Comment: The size of the physics body is updated automatically (or at least it should be). You can use `skView.showsPhysics = true` to check the `SKPhysicsBody` is being updated correctly. However, I tested your code and everything seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may not use SKAction to scale the shapeNode. SKAction is just an "action", it will not change the property of a node. Try this instead:

```
shapeNode.xScale = 16.0
shapeNode.yScale = 16.0
```

Then it will return a new scaled size to you.

Comment: You can use an `SKAction` to scale the shapeNode, did you test the code in the question? Also, most `SKAction`s are used to change a property of a node.

Comment: @ABakerSmith Sorry, by meaning "change", I mean SKAction cannot help you store the changed value. You cannot get the value the action changed, which is shapeNode.path returned in your case. But you can use xScale/yScale to get the scaled path value.